# MYSQL - Specific Request SLOW Multi count

Tags: mysql, performance, count

[image: Request]

Explain :

[image: Explain]

Rows Result : 72.

I have trouble understanding the "Explain". I wonder where I go wrong. For me the index, and the index group are ok.

Can you help me ?

Comment: You are looking to make this faster? The Explain says you have no keys joining table atS which will be slow. Dates with date functions do not work fast for comparison in mysql

Answer (score 0):

The big performance problem involves

```
  YEAR(..) = YEAR(..)  AND
  WEEK(..) = WEEK(..)
```

By hiding columns inside functions, no index is useful.  In this particular case, it is awkward to pull them out.

If you have a new enough version of MySQL or MariaDB, consider adding an integer column that contains a "week number" that "generated persistently" from your dates.  Then index that column.  Then there won't be repeated full-table-scans, but instead simple, quick, index lookups.